# Как соединить для одного subject два прослушивания данных при разных моделях данных?

Tags: android, android-studio, map, rxjava, observer

Вот два прослушивания данных (из строки поиска).

```
publishSubject
            .startWith("") 
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .map(String::toLowerCase) //вниз регистр весь
            .switchMap((Function<String, ObservableSource<List<Actor>>>) s -> RoomProvider
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .getDaoActor().getByName("%" + s + "%")
                    .toObservable())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap((Function<List<Actor>, ObservableSource<Actor>>) Observable::fromIterable)
            .subscribe(actor -> Log.d("mLog",actor.getName()));
//___________________________________________________________________________
 publishSubject
            .startWith("") //самый первый онНекст
            .debounce(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //задержка вызова 1 сек
            .map(String::toLowerCase) //вниз регистр весь
            .switchMap((Function<String, ObservableSource<List<Movie>>>) s -> RoomProvider
                    .getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                    .getDaoMovie().getByName("%" + s + "%").toObservable())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap((Function<List<Movie>, ObservableSource<Movie>>) Observable::fromIterable)
            .subscribe(movie -> Log.d("mLog", movie.getName()));
```

Нужно как то соединить их в один запрос и потом получить результат.
Данные получаю из bd через Room. 
Модели разные. в первом прослушивании List<'Actors'> а во втором List<'Movies'>.
Если я правильно понимаю то варианты типа zip, concat работают только с одинаковыми моделями, либо у меня что то не получается.

Comment: Zip для разных данных работает. Типа так: `Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, (o1, o2) -> new Pair<>(o1, o2))`

Answer (score 0):

`zip`, `concat` и `combineLatest` могут работать с разными типами. Например:

```
Observable.combineLatest(actorsObservable, moviesObservable, BothParams::of)
```

или

```
Observable.combineLatest(actorsObservable, moviesObservable, BothParams::of)
```

В обоих случаях результатом будет `Observable<BothParams<List<Actors>, List<Movies>>>`